# uemacs 4.0.15 strange key bindings

Tags: keyboard, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

Playing around with uemacs I noticed that some of the default alternative key bindings are set to the Fn key in combination with a different key (for example, an alternative for 'help' is set to `FNh`, i.e. press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>). From what I know, using the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key as a meta key is not possible (since doing the command `xev` and pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> does not generate any keycode). Is there a work around for using Fn in uemacs?

Comment: This `FNh` is an internal name in uemacs. It is not related to the `Fn` key on laptops. Which of the several uemacs/microemacs are you using?

Comment: It's from github, version 4.0.15. What do you mean by internal name?

Answer (score 2):

OP is likely referring to

- this project on github: https://github.com/snaewe/uemacs,
- created by an import from https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/editors/uemacs/em-4.0.15-lt.tar.gz

Referring to the source (on github, since it is easily linked and not much changed from the import):

- [emacs.rc](https://github.com/snaewe/uemacs/blob/master/emacs.rc) has bindings like this:

  `bind-to-key help FN;`

  which use `FN` as an *internal name*, e.g.,
- bind.c in functions [cmdstr](https://github.com/snaewe/uemacs/blob/master/bind.c#L558) and [stock](https://github.com/snaewe/uemacs/blob/master/bind.c#L659) translates that from/to the mask value `SPEC` (special key).
- uemacs only knows about *terminals* (no X), so `xev` is irrelevant
- uemacs detects *special keys* when you type them into a terminal because they are *escape sequences*.  In particular, those which begin with CSI, e.g., <kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> tell it to mark those with `SPEC`.
- It does this in input.c function [`getcmd`](https://github.com/snaewe/uemacs/blob/master/input.c#L346) by ORing the `SPEC` flag with the *final character* of the escape sequence which it read.  For instance, a cursor up-arrow would be <kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.
- in [ebind.h](https://github.com/snaewe/uemacs/blob/master/ebind.h#L391), that corresponds to the [`backline`](https://github.com/snaewe/uemacs/blob/master/basic.c#L241) function.

So there is no literal "FN" used for a key-binding, nor is the special key `FN` used (which you may find on various small keyboards, e.g., laptops).  It is used only to make the bindings more readable.

Further reading:

- [Why do different terminals have different values for keys in the .inputrc file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26055/why-do-different-terminals-have-different-values-for-keys-in-the-inputrc-file/265460#265460)