# Ctrl-Arrow does not work anymore after installing Prezto

Tags: bash, zsh, rxvt, prezto

I have this in my `.inputrc`:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
set completion-ignore-case on

# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\eOc": forward-word
"\eOd": backward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

Also, I didn't touch anything in `.zprezto/modules/editor/init.zsh`, where `bindkey` instructions are defined.

However, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> my terminal (URxvt) blinks and nothing happens. On the other hand, in XTerm it works. It appears to be a URxvt problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key bindings shown are for xterm (and programs which copy xterm's behavior).  `urxvt` is a descendant of `rxvt`, which uses *different* key bindings.  By default, <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>left</kbd> for rxvt/urxvt sends <kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.  You can see this by running

```
cat -v
```

and typing that key combination.  It will echo as `^[Od`.  The same issue applies to the other cursor keys.

`urxvt` provides a resource setting `keysym.sym` (an extension of a feature introduced in `rxvt`) which you *could* use to modify the keys sent by these terminals to more closely match `xterm`.  That would would be a resource setting like this:

```
URxvt.keysym.Control-0xff51:    \033[1;5D
```

where (as indicated in the manual page), `Control` is the modifier, and `0xff51` is the code for the cursor-left key which you can get using `xev`.

To get all of the keys, you'd have to add a resource for each of the keys (and modifier).

Further reading:

- [rxvt-unicode (ouR XVT, unicode) - (a VT102 emulator for the X window
  system)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=urxvt&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports)
- [Why do different terminals have different values for keys in the .inputrc file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265460/105132)

Comment: The `keysym` setting does indeed work! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The `~/.inputrc` file is a bash thing, not a `zsh` thing as far as I know. It controls the behavior of `readline`, the `zsh` equivalent of which is [`zle`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Zsh-Line-Editor). You can modify its behavior using the [`bindkey`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-bindkey) command.

So, to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> back, add these lines to your `~/.zshrc` (there might be a better place for them, an equivalent to `~/.inputrc` but I don't know it and `~/.zshrc` works):

```
bindkey "\eOc" forward-word
bindkey "\eOd" backward-word
bindkey "\e[1;5C" forward-word
bindkey "\e[1;5D" backward-word
bindkey "\e[5C" forward-word
bindkey "\e[5D" backward-word
bindkey "\e\e[C" forward-word
bindkey "\e\e[D" backward-word
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately it still does not work. The terminal just blinks. I also found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158794/in-prezto-how-to-get-ctrl-rarrow-working) on StackOverflow. Neither that helped...

Comment: @rubik 1) you _are_ using `zsh` right? 2) Did you start a new terminal (or source `.zshrc`) after changing it? 3) Did they work before installing prezto? I mean in `zsh` not in `bash`. 4) URxvt is sometimes strange, does it work in a different terminal emulator?

Comment: Yes, I tried both methods. Actually I tried with xterm and it works, so it's a URxvt problem! Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @rubik ah, yes, I thought that might be it. The different emulators define key combinations differently. You should be able to find what `Ctrl+Left` sends by typing `Ctrl+V` and then hitting `Ctrl+Left`. That should give you an idea of what code it is looking for. Odd though, it works on `rxvt` on my system, installing `rxvt-unicode` now to check.

Comment: @rubik it works fine on `urxvt` as well. Are you sure you copied _all_ the lines? Also, you might have a user-specific setting that is screwing things up. Try creating a new user, adding the lines to the user's `~/.zshrc` and testing there.

Comment: Argh. Actually even with `Ctrl-V` the terminal just blinks! Something must be wrong with my configuration. Will update.

Comment: @rubik please edit your question and include the details from these comments.  The fact that it works in another terminal is particularly important